# Where is the "Unpublish" button on Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to temporarily unpublish my app from the Play Store. I cannot find the button. Screenshot below is from the `Store Details` screen. I dont see it on the `APK` screen either.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: UnPublish App]
Please find the attached screen shot . There will be a small link top left . "Unpublish App"

Comment: thanks, got it. Didnt realize the unpublished text was a button. Will mark as answer in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

check it in your application detail page

[image]